# Element-wise matrix addition on output of cellfun in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a function `d2l_dgamma_dgammaT` that outputs 6×6 matrices. I want to perform element-wise addition on these matrices without using the for loop below. A_gamma_temp is a cell array containing 6x6 matrices and A_gamma should be a single 6x6 matrix containing the element wise sum of all these matrices. How can I do this?

```
A_gamma_temp = cellfun(@(a,b) d2l_dgamma_dgammaT(sigma_sq, tau_sq, a, b), ...
    wb_sorted, zb_sorted, 'uniformoutput', false);

A_gamma = zeros(6,6);

for ii = 1:size(A_gamma_temp, 1)
    A_gamma = A_gamma + A_gamma_temp{ii};
end
```

Comment: A_gamma_temp is a cell array of size 6x6 or 6x1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `A_gamma_temp` is a cell array containing 6×6 matrices, and that `A_gamma` should be a single 6×6 matrix which is the sum of all these individual matrices, this should work:

```
A_gamma = sum(cat(3, A_gamma_temp{:}),3)
```

For future reference, it really helps if you

- provide a [minimal working example](http://minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html)
- formulate your desired inputs/outputs in such a way that we don't have to make guesses and assumptions.

Just remember, *we* know *nothing* about what you want to do, or have already done. You're just more likely to get a good answer, and quicker too, if you spend a bit more time on formulating your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a single number result, you may try this too -

```
A_gamma = sum(vertcat(A_gamma_temp{:}))
```

Since OP had this - `A_gamma = zeros(6,6);`, I am not sure if a single number is expected.